# Ошибка индекса коллекции. Не могу обратиться к объекту коллекции но индексу

Tags: unity3d

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class grid_ : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private float speses;
    public List<GameObject> gridobject = new List<GameObject>(48);
    public GameObject[] arreypl = new GameObject[48];

    private void Start()
    {
        int n = 0;
        foreach(GameObject i in arreypl)
        {
           gridobject[n] = i;
            n++;
        }
    }
    public grid_(int width, int height, float speses)
    {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.speses = speses;
        for(int x = 0; x < height; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < width; y++)
            {
                int n = Random.Range(0, gridobject.Count);          
                Debug.Log(gridobject[n]);
                GameObject a = gridobject[n];
                Instantiate(a, Get_world_position(x, y), Quaternion.identity);
                Debug.Log(n);
                gridobject.RemoveAt(n);
                Debug.Log(n);
            }
        }
    }
    private Vector3 Get_world_position(int x, int y)
    {
        return new Vector3(x, y) * speses;
    }
}
```

> Выдаёт ошибку ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
> Parameter name: index
> подскажите как исправить.

Answer (score 0):

`Random.Range` согласно [описанию](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) возвращает число из указанного диапазона, **включая** обе границы диапазона. В случае возврата `gridobject.Count` естественно произойдёт выход за границы допустимого диапазона индексов списка `[0, gridobject.Count - 1]`. Так что нужно вычесть 1 из правой границы:

```
int n = Random.Range(0, gridobject.Count - 1);
```

Comment: но код не работает даже тогда когда число n << array. Count

Comment: @Hellplay2017 Добавьте в вопрос полный стек-трейс ошибки, он большой, но добавьте весь. Там будет и строчка в которой ошибка и много чего полезного.